# How to refresh/reload a managedObjectContext?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am developing and iOS app and I have a problem with the `managedObjectContext`. I am loading a ViewController and from there I request an object from API and then I just save it to the local app database using Core Data. I already save the master context using `save:`, but I need to refresh the `managedObjectContext` because it seems like the object isn't on it and I want to render this new object I added to the database. At the moment if I reload this ViewController's action now this object is on the context and I can render it.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  Notification *notification = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

  if ([notification.isRead isEqualToNumber:@NO]) {
    [self sendNotificationData:notification];
    notification.isRead = @YES;
  }

  [self insertPost:notification.notificatableId];

  Post *post = [self fetchObjectfrom:@"Post"
                   withPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"objectId == %@", notification.notificatableId]];
}

- (void)insertPost:(NSString *)postId
{

  NSDictionary *parameters = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:postId, @"notification[post_id]", nil];

  [[AkdemiaAPIClient sharedClient] POST:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/notifications/%@/get_post",postId] parameters:parameters
                        success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id JSON) {

                          [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES
                                                                  forKey:@"PostNotificationsDetailsNotificationName"];
                          [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

                          [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"PostNotificationsDetailsSucceedNotificationName"
                                                                              object:nil];

                          AkdemiaSyncEngine *syncEngine = [[AkdemiaSyncEngine alloc] init];
                          [syncEngine processJSONDataRecordsIntoCoreData:JSON forComponent:kFeed];

                          [[AkdemiaCoreDataController sharedInstance] saveBackgroundContext];
                          [[AkdemiaCoreDataController sharedInstance] saveMasterContext];

                        } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {

                          [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"PostNotificationsDetailsErrorNotificationName"
                                                                              object:nil];

                        }];
}
```

That's the code where I request the object and then I save it in the database. Using:

```
[[AkdemiaCoreDataController sharedInstance] saveBackgroundContext];
[[AkdemiaCoreDataController sharedInstance] saveMasterContext];
```

I called `save:` method

Comment: Do you have some code to show? Might make it easier to understand your issue.

Comment: you mentioned save:, but did you [myContext saveContext]. Is it a persistent store content? memory store? iCloud backed? Can you git a tad more info please mate :) and as per @JamesSugrue can you post a little code so we can see where your context tis created, used, re-used in the class you're calling it from etc...

Comment: @JamesSugrue I already edit the question

Comment: In that case there's no need to refresh at all. When you "create" the object elsewhere, it will "refresh" the MOC itself.. i.e. When you create the object (or objects) fire a `[myManagedObjectContext save]` and it'll persist it and the the context will be updated. Along with any other contexts which are relying on the data too.